# Omniauth facebook - Auth info fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, omniauth-facebook

I am trying to setup omniauth for a website for login through facebook. The issue is facebook is not sending the 'info' field.

I have setup 2 facebook apps for different environment.

For one app the response has the fields

```
#<OmniAuth::AuthHash credentials=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash expires=true expires_at=14
42913734 token="CAAU6NSaozowBANJoDeZCakDuUZAiIZBGQ5cmFYRTwQwo7SK2JK7uhcRK7WIadpp
zjKfict9pMASS2k9XJZBTgnI8WJvJA42er9Xj8nuoeLjbEQo8TKB7b5hVlsOwRs5kcPpOPwyUTUc0ekF
uu2w4ubNZBMXZBw5xjGkQwZBZA46fATGOvDXJSrWOOAiQteWnkSO9JkeZC2SfmZCQqcSR0zdV52"> ex
tra=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash raw_info=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash id="xxxxxxxxxx" na
me="xxxxxxx">> info=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash::InfoHash image="http://graph.facebo
ok.com/xxxxxxxxxxx/picture" name="xxxx"> provider="facebook" uid="xxxxxxxx">
```

In the development env I get the response

```
#<OmniAuth::AuthHash credentials=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash expires=true expires_at=14
42912896 token="CAAPK1ZAgrDtEBAKKvcj4jGu6iaIxYYJV7LZCJ6MZCELZCgNyowkqPeB5kHBsVw4
ZBKoZCv4DD6my4s8qhO1hJyEFzcb1IpKt03ydzWORZCR3PCf1bw6A9jRudmcJn1N37WgqckmuKUj4k1y
qb3fcRpNPxAxx0asXJlaUJTcVR5wi0sRIOc9l3yFm6XyuMA464MBz5vt9AvNcVB9DAGm5kHr"> extra
=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash raw_info=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash email="xxxxx@yahoo.co.in"
first_name="xxxx" gender="male" id="xxxxx" last_name="xxxx" link="h
ttps://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/xxxx/" locale="en_US" na
me="xxxx" timezone=10 updated_time="2015-06-06T03:35:33+0000" verified=tru
e>> info=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash::InfoHash email="xxxxxxx" first_name="
xx" image="http://graph.facebook.com/xxx/picture" last_name="xxxxx" name="xxxxx" urls=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash Facebook="https://www.facebook.c
om/app_scoped_user_id/xxxxx/"> verified=true> provider="facebook" ui
d="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
```

I wonder if it is a app level setting because the code is same for both. Only difference on the app side is one is API v2.3 and other is 2.4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is difference when you use v2.3 and v2.4.

In your `config/initializers/devise.rb` file or wherever you have put your API key, you have to add `info_fields`, besides `scope`,

example

```
config.omniauth :facebook, APP["facebook_id"], APP["facebook_secret"],
    :scope => 'email,public_profile', info_fields: 'email,name'
```

Comment: Yes, exactly so it is the only version mismatch which is the issue? because i was able to fix by providing the info_fields then wondered why did the other app does not need it. Thanks

Comment: @sethi It's explicitly stated in the FB changelogs https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4 that with v2.4 you have to specify **each** field you want returned from the Graph API.

Comment: to get the verified account flag, I had to add it:  info_fields: 'email,name,verified'